# Iterating through a set using pointers: Undefined reference to custom class C++

Tags: c++, class, iterator

I have a custom class that I am using to store a data entry. The UUID is the pair <ID, DataType> where DataType is an enumerated list.
The cpp file contains:

```
DataClass::DataClass(int id, DataType dataType) :
    _id(id), 
    _type(dataType), 
    _text(), 
    _value()
{}
```

And the header file contains:

```
class DataClass 
{
public:
    DataClass(int id, DataType dataType);

    int _id; 
    DataType _type;
    std::string _text; 
    uint _value; 
};
```

I then have a second class that is where the majority of the data analysis occurs, and contains the collection of data as a `std::set<DataClass>`. This is a big set so I want to utilise pointers as much as possible obviously.

The header for the class contains:

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
    std::set<DataClass> _dataSet;
    
    std::set<DataClass>* getDataSet();

    DataClass* getDataEntry(int testID, DataType testDataType);
};
```

Then within the cpp file I have:

```
MyClass::MyClass() :
    _dataSet() 
{}

std::set<DataClass>* MyClass::getDataSet(){return &(this->_dataSet);}

DataClass* MyClass::getDataEntry(int testID, DataType testDataType)
{
    std::set<DataClass> *dataSet = this->getDataSet();
    auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(*dataSet), std::end(*dataSet), 
        [&], (DataClass dataentry), {return dataEntry.isEntryEqual(std::make_pair(testID, testDataType));});
    return (DataClass *) &(*it);
}
```

However, I get errors:

```
In function `bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<DataClass::isEntryEqual(std::pair<int, DataType>)::{lambda(DataClass)#1}>::operator()<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<DataClass> >(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<DataClass>)':
Undefined reference to DataClass::~DataClass()
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. I have simplified the code slightly to write this question, as the full code is much longer/more complex.

Any help would be really appreciated !

Comment: Unforunately you've simplified your code so much that you've removed the error. The error message is telling you that you've declared a destructor for `DataClass` but you haven't defined one.

Comment: Your definition of `getDataSet` is not returning a pointer. It has a different signature than the declaration. Also, names like `_ID` are not allowed.

Comment: Should be easy to fix, either define a destructor or delete the declaration.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The parameter in the lambda should be `const auto& dataentry` Otherwise you're requiring a copy of the entire thing for every comparison

Comment: @john yeah, Im not sure how to ask the question without copying huge amounts of code that probably isnt pertinent.

Comment: You remove code that isn't relevant. Just get rid anything and everything while still keeping the error. It shouldn't be that hard to get a 20 line program that still has the error you don't understand. Then post that code. Doesn't matter that the code no longer does anything useful. As long as it's complete and demonstrates the error then it's enough to get the question answered.

Comment: I suspect you declared but did not define the destructor `~DataClass()`. Try making it `~DataClass() = default;`. Also, you'll want to make the lambda take a reference, as others suggested, and also you should validate that the value was found in the map before de-referencing the iterator in your return statement in `getDataEntry()`. I'd also suggest you use `make_pair()` outside of the lambda  since it's never changing, so then you don't have to construct it anew on every comparison.